# refering to Templates c++

Tags: c++, templates

Considering Template Class
when do we have to refer explicitly to template, and when the compiler "understands that we meant it"

considering the following occurences:

1) function return value & arguements

2) variable declaration inside function

3) namespace `SomeClass<T>::` vs. `SomeClass::`

Is there any rule? I saw sometimes the use is of:

```
SomeClass
```

and sometimes: `SomeClass<T>`

and I didn't get the rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class template parameters may *only* be omitted inside the implementation of that class, where they implicitly add the appropriate template specifiers to the class and when referring to a non-dependent base class (non-dependent as in "does not reuse any template arguments"). For example:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class C { /* here C is the same as C<T, U> */ };

template<typename T>
class C<void, T> { /* here C is the same as C<void, T> */ };

template<>
class C<void, void> { /* here C is the same as C<void, void> */ };

template<typename> struct Base { };

struct DerivedA : Base<void>
{ /* here Base is the same as Base<void> */ };

template<typename T>
struct DerivedB : Base<T>
{ /* here Base is invalid, since Base<T> depends on a template argument */ };
```

Function templates may have their template parameters omitted, if they can be deduced from their arguments:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T f);

f(3); // equivalent to f<int>(3) if no other overload exists
```

Additionally, there are default template arguments, which leads to [something really funky](https://ideone.com/gK11Gq):

```
template<typename T = void>
class D
{
    // Here D is D<T>, but D<> is D<void> instead!
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard describes all scenarios in [temp.local]:

> 1. Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected-class-name can be used as
>      a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a
>      *template-argument-list*, as a *template-argument* for a *template template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the
>      *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. **Otherwise, it is equivalent to
>      the *template-name* followed by the template-parameters of the class
>      template enclosed in `<>`.**
> 2. Within the scope of a class template specialization or partial specialization, when the injected-class-name is used as a *type-name*,
>      it is equivalent to the template-name followed by the
>      template-arguments of the classtemplate specialization or partial
>      specialization enclosed in `<>`.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<template<class> class T> class A { };
> template<class T> class Y;
> template<> class Y<int> {
>   Y* p;                             // meaning Y<int>
>   Y<char>* q;                       // meaning Y<char>
>   A<Y>* a;                          // meaning A<::Y>
>   class B {
>     template<class> friend class Y; // meaning ::Y
>   };
> };
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

This only works inside the class template (i.e. the scope of the injected-class-name), and only if the name is accessed from a corresponding scope:

> When the normal name of the template (i.e., the name from the
>   enclosing scope, not the injected-class-name) is used, it always
>   refers to the class template itself and not a specialization of the
>   template. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> class X {
>   X* p;             // meaning X<T>
>   X<T>* p2;
>   X<int>* p3;
>   ::X* p4;         // error: missing template argument list
>                    // ::X does not refer to the injected-class-name
> };
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

And for base classes, where the base is not dependent:

> A lookup that finds an injected-class-name (10.2) can result in an
>   ambiguity in certain cases (for example, if it is found in more than
>   one base class). If all of the injected-class-names that are found
>   refer to specializations of the same class template, and if the name
>   is used as a *template-name*, the reference refers to the class
>   template itself and not a specialization thereof, and is not
>   ambiguous.  [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct Base { };
> template <class T> struct Derived: Base<int>, Base<char> {
>   typename Derived::Base b;             // error: ambiguous
>   typename Derived::Base<double> d;     // OK
> };
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

We can modify the example slightly to show what would be valid:

```
template <class T> struct Base { };
template <class T> struct Derived: Base<char> {
  typename Derived::Base b;             // Ok: b refers to Base<char>
};
```